# template functions with shared private data

Tags: c++, templates, static, private

I'm looking for 'best-practice' in the following situation:
In general, there are three common ways to share private data between two (or more) non-member functions with differential advantages and disadvantages:

```
// Example 1: using 'static' class

// HPP
namespace foo {
    class bar
    {
    private:
        static const char* const s_private;
        bar();

    public:
        static void s_method0();
        static void s_method1();
    }; /* class bar */
} /* namespace foo */

// CPP
namespace foo {
    const char* const bar::s_private = "why do I need to be visible in HPP?";

    void bar::s_method0() { std::cout << "s_method0 said: " << s_private << std::endl; }
    void bar::s_method1() { std::cout << "s_method1 said: " << s_private << std::endl; } 
} /* namespace foo */


// Example 2: using unnamed-namespace

// HPP
namespace foo { 
    void bar0(); 
    void bar1();
} /* namespace foo */

// CPP
namespace foo {
    namespace {
        const char* const g_anonymous = "why do I need external linkage?";
    } /* unnamed-namespace */

    void bar0() { std::cout << "bar0 said: " << g_anonymous << std::endl; }
    void bar1() { std::cout << "bar1 said: " << g_anonymous << std::endl; }
} /* namespace foo */


// Example 3: using static keyword in namespace-scope

// HPP
namespace foo { 
    void bar0(); 
    void bar1();
} /* namespace foo */

// CPP
namespace foo {
    static const char* const g_internal = "nobody outside this file can see me and I don't have external linkage";

    void bar0() { std::cout << "bar0 said: " << g_internal << std::endl; }
    void bar1() { std::cout << "bar1 said: " << g_internal << std::endl; }
} /* namespace foo */
```

I prefer 'Example 3' because it's as close to the intention as it could be.
But now I'm running in some problem's using templated functions. 'Example 1' seems to be the only way to solve this:

```
// HPP
namespace foo {
    class bar
    {
    private:
        static const char* const s_private;
        bar();

    public:
        template<typename T> static void s_method0() { std::cout << "s_method0 said: " << s_private << std::endl; }
        template<typename T> static void s_method1() { std::cout << "s_method1 said: " << s_private << std::endl; }
    }; /* class bar */
} /* namespace foo */

// CPP
namespace foo {
    const char* const bar::s_private = "why do I need to be visible in HPP?";
} /* namespace foo */
```

That's unsatisfying. Especialy because there are other (in this case methods) non-member function which should be in the same (in this case class-) scope, which don't need to access this private data.

Does anybody know an elegant solution?

Thanks for any help.
Best regards.

Comment: Your complaint is that class variables are visible everywhere in the class?

Comment: Uh, why should they be in the same class scope if they don't need to access the data?

Comment: Just a comment: you write `const char const* s_private;`. This declares `s_private` as a pointer to a constant char. If you want this to be a constant pointer to a constant char, then this should be `const char * const`.

Comment: @Daniel: Sry, you are right. Just a copy-n-paste problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had played around with the different techniques. My idea, using the unnamed namespace in the header file, was to 'mark' the 'shared'-classes as 'header-file-only'. Sure, due to the fact they aren't containing public members you cannot make nasty things anyway with it. But I thought it would be more close to the intention.

But I was wrong! After thinking about this I'm in shame. It's so logically simple. This example is showing what's the problem with it (entire code for clearness):

```
// header0.hpp
#ifndef HPP_HEADER0_INCLUDED
#define HPP_HEADER0_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace ns {
    template<typename T> void header0_func0();
    template<typename T> void header0_func1();

    namespace {
        class header0
        {
            template<typename> friend void ns::header0_func0();
            template<typename> friend void ns::header0_func1();

            static std::string s_private;
        }; /* class header0 */
    } /* unnamed */

    template<typename T> void header0_func0() { std::cout << "header0_func0: " << header0::s_private << std::endl; }
    template<typename T> void header0_func1() { std::cout << "header0_func1: " << header0::s_private << std::endl; }
} /* namespace ns */

#endif /* HPP_HEADER0_INCLUDED */ 


// header1.hpp
#ifndef HPP_HEADER1_INCLUDED
#define HPP_HEADER1_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace ns {
    template<typename T> void header1_func0();
    template<typename T> void header1_func1();

    namespace {
        class header1
        {
            template<typename> friend void ns::header1_func0();
            template<typename> friend void ns::header1_func1();

            static std::string s_private;
        }; /* class header1 */
    } /* unnamed */

    template<typename T> void header1_func0() { std::cout << "header1_func0: " << header1::s_private << std::endl; }
    template<typename T> void header1_func1() { std::cout << "header1_func0: " << header1::s_private << std::endl; }
} /* namespace ns */

#endif /* HPP_HEADER1_INCLUDED */


// source.cpp
#include "header0.hpp"
#include "header1.hpp"

std::string ns::header0::s_private = "header0 private data definition by source.cpp",
            ns::header1::s_private = "header1 private data definition by source.cpp";

namespace {
    // hide private class
    class source
    {
        source();
        ~source();

        static source s_instance;
    };

    source::source() { 
        std::cout << "source.cpp:\n";
        ns::header0_func0<int>();
        ns::header0_func1<int>();
        ns::header1_func0<int>();
        ns::header1_func1<int>();
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    source::~source() { }
    source source::s_instance;
} /* unnamed */
```

By now everything seems to be OK. But what happen's if we try to use our headers in other translation units? Let's take a look:

```
// main.cpp
#include "header0.hpp"
#include "header1.hpp"

int main()
{   
    std::cout << "main.cpp:\n";
    ns::header0_func0<int>();
    ns::header0_func1<int>();
    ns::header1_func0<int>();
    ns::header1_func1<int>();
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

What happens is, that we are ending with 2 unresolved externals. So, is the linker just an idiot? No, he is not. Thinking about what are unnamed namespace used for, we know what's going on. An unnamed namespace has an unique identifier in each translation unit. Thus, in our main.cpp, the linker doesn't know the definition of our private data in source.cpp.
So, what happens if we define this private data in main.cpp - just to bring matters to a head - ?

```
// main.cpp
#include "header0.hpp"
#include "header1.hpp"

std::string ns::header0::s_private = "header0 private data definition by main.cpp",
            ns::header1::s_private = "header1 private data definition by main.cpp";

int main()
{   
    std::cout << "main.cpp:\n";
    ns::header0_func0<int>();
    ns::header0_func1<int>();
    ns::header1_func0<int>();
    ns::header1_func1<int>();
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Now, everything is compiling and getting linked 'correctly' - or rather, it seems so.
This is the console output of that program:

```
source.cpp:
header0_func0: header0 private data definition by source.cpp
header0_func1: header0 private data definition by source.cpp
header1_func0: header1 private data definition by source.cpp
header1_func0: header1 private data definition by source.cpp

main.cpp:
header0_func0: header0 private data definition by source.cpp
header0_func1: header0 private data definition by source.cpp
header1_func0: header1 private data definition by source.cpp
header1_func0: header1 private data definition by source.cpp
```

That means: If undefined behavior is what you are looking for, here you are.
In other words: Based on the explanation above: Don't use unnamed namespace in header files to encapsulate private shared data.

And the last question is, "what's the solution?"
If you don't want to use 'static' (utility) classes, you should prefer my first posted solution (only changed code):

```
// header0.hpp
// ...
namespace ns {
    // ...  
    namespace detail { 
        class header0 { /*...*/ };
    } /* namespace detail */

    template<typename T> void header0_func0() { std::cout << "header0_func0: " << detail::header0::s_private << std::endl; }
    template<typename T> void header0_func1() { std::cout << "header0_func1: " << detail::header0::s_private << std::endl; }
} /* namespace ns */
// ...

// header1.hpp
// ...
namespace ns {
    // ...  
    namespace detail { 
        class header1 { /*...*/ };
    } /* namespace detail */

    template<typename T> void header0_func0() { std::cout << "header0_func0: " << detail::header1::s_private << std::endl; }
    template<typename T> void header0_func1() { std::cout << "header0_func1: " << detail::header1::s_private << std::endl; }
} /* namespace ns */
// ...

// source.cpp
// ...
std::string ns::detail::header0::s_private = "header0 private data definition by source.cpp",
            ns::detail::header1::s_private = "header1 private data definition by source.cpp";
// ...
```

I'm looking forward to any comment. Best regards.

Comment: How is the final code significantly different from encapsulating each set of function templates in a separate class?

Comment: All functions are just functions located in the same namescope. Thus, that's the difference. However, that's not about performance. It's about best-practice design.

Answer (score 1):

This is, somewhat unfortunately, an issue that springs quite often with template.

But may I suggest that you are over-engineering here ?

The truth is, whether you look at Loki code (by Andrei Alexandrescu) or Boost code (infamous David Abrahams notably), no-one really bothered to provide a *better* privacy.

Rather, they simply relied on convention and used a `Private` namespace (Loki) or a `detail` namespace (Boost, with sometimes a longer and more descriptive name to prevent clashes).

It's annoying, but there is not much you can do in practice.... though I actually have a solution for your specific problem ;)

```
// Evil solution!

#ifdef MY_SUPER_MACRO
#  error "MY_SUPER_MACRO is already defined!"
#endif

#define MY_SUPER_MACRO "Some string"

template <typename T> void foo() { std::cout << "foo - " MY_SUPER_MACRO "\n"; }
template <typename T> void bar() { std::cout << "bar - " MY_SUPER_MACRO "\n"; }

#undef MY_SUPER_MACRO
```

And hop, I achieved locality in a header with an evil macro :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my problem is more general ;) I was looking for 'best-practice' sharing arbitrary private data between template non-member functions.

Comment: @FrEEzE2046: by "arbitrary private data", do you mean static non-constant data ? Global Variables should be avoided.

Comment: Yes, I mean static non-constant data. But there's no reason to use global variables. You can declare some class like "shared_private_data" in an unnamed namespace in your source file and allow control access to it.

Answer (score 0):

What about that?

```
namespace foo {
    namespace detail {
        class shared 
        { 
            template<typename> friend void bar0();
            template<typename> friend void bar1();

            static const char* const m_private; 
        }; /* class shared */
    } /* namespace detail */

    template<typename T> void bar0() { std::cout << "bar0 said: " << detail::shared::m_private << std::endl; }
    template<typename T> void bar1() { std::cout << "bar1 said: " << detail::shared::m_private << std::endl; }
} /* namespace foo */
```

EDIT 2:
OBSOLETE ANSWER. THIS CODE ISN'T WORKING! POSTED AN EXPLANATION BELOW.

EDIT:
In 'real code' I would replace namespace detail by an unnamed namespace. This would bring up the possibility to add other shared resources in different header files using the same name-scope:

```
namespace foo {
    template<typename T> void bar0();
    template<typename T> void bar1();
    template<typename T> void bar2();
    template<typename T> void bar3();


    namespace {
        class shared0 
        { 
            template<typename> friend void foo::bar0();
            template<typename> friend void foo::bar1();

            static const char* const m_private0; 
        }; /* class shared0 */

        class shared1
        { 
            template<typename> friend void foo::bar2();
            template<typename> friend void foo::bar3();

            static const char* const m_private1;    
        }; /* class shared1 */
    } /* unnamed */


    template<typename T> void bar0() { std::cout << "bar0 said: " << shared0::m_private0 << std::endl; }
    template<typename T> void bar1() { std::cout << "bar1 said: " << shared0::m_private0 << std::endl; }

    template<typename T> void bar2() { std::cout << "bar0 said: " << shared1::m_private1 << std::endl; }
    template<typename T> void bar3() { std::cout << "bar1 said: " << shared1::m_private1 << std::endl; }
} /* namespace foo */
```

Comment: As for me, that is the case when readability is suffering  from such constructions, that try to do your code so abstract. Is it really so bad to declare m_private in .h file? No one even sees what exactly m_private stores.

Comment: -1 The use of unnamed namespaces and "static" at namespace scope in combination with templates leads to ODR violations in your case which invokes undefined behaviour. There is no good reason to declare m_private in an unnamed namespace or with "static" (internal linkage).

Comment: @selibitze: 'm_private' isn't in an unnamed namespace directly! Did you see it's declared in a class? Thus ODR isn't violated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your complaint/concern is that unlike with templates, with non-templates, one can define the function bodies inside the CPP, rather than the header, in which case they can access non-class statics, which are "invisible" to the outside world, including member functions defined in the header.  This is all true.

However, remember that there's nothing stopping one defining other member functions in the CPP as well, in which case, they'd be equally able to access the static data.  So really, the situation is no different.  Your complaint is based on a false dichotomy.

If you genuinely want to prevent *anything* but `s_method0<T>()` and `s_method1<T>()` accessing `s_private`, then you must put them all in a dedicated class.  It's as simple as that.  This would be the case even for non-templates.

Comment: All functions are utility functions. So, it would be nasty to encapsulate 'each one' of them in a seperate class. I could use anonymous/unnamed class, but I don't see the possibility to define a static member of an unnamed class.

Comment: @FrEEzE2046: This is true.  But I would recommend changing your question title, because it really has little to do with templates!

Comment: I don't think so. The problem appers only for template functions, because you need to define them in your header file. So, you cannot hide private data in a source file. Thus, it has to do with templates and sharing private data.

Comment: @FrEEzE2046: As I explained in my answer, this is not limited to function templates.  Yes, you're forced to put them in your header.  But even if that weren't the case, the "problem" would still exist.

Comment: Sure, it does. But there are other solutions which are more intention like.